# Compare-and-swap for HTTP PUT?

Tags: http, put, compare-and-swap, preconditions

Is there a way to make a [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)-style mechanism the *only* way to modify certain resources, whilst following the HTTP standard?

There's an [`If-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24) header which implements the correct behaviour however this header is optional: as far as I can tell, if `If-Match` is not provided, the server should honour the `PUT`.  (That is, it's up to the client to decide whether it wants to compare-and-swap, or just swap.)  Would it be acceptable to respond with `412 Precondition Failed` if the client tries to `PUT` or `POST` without providing an `If-Match` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you *can* use status code 428 Precondition Required (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6585.html#status-428).